# How to insert the value in a field added manually without the script imgur generating another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, imgur

I am using imgur's library to upload images, I have it running here without any inconvenience: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3hwqnoc/4/) the only problem I present is with the validation of PHP, that when the form field is generated, php does not detect it, It is because, the following field: `<input name="cover_page" class="image-url" value="">` is only generated when an image is uploaded

To avoid this problem I want to add the following field `<input name="cover_page" class="image-url" value="">` in a manul way, and that the script inserts the value when uploading the image in it without the script generating me another input

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi  for the other part  you can  add manually the input inside the form '#news'

i see you do have input cover_page in your page  replace it with this

`<input id="IMG_URL"name="cover_page" class="image-url" value=""/>`

then  after upload change it's value then `frm.serialize` will upload `cover_page`

replace `feedback` function with this

```
var feedback = function(res) {
  if (res.success === true) {
    var get_link = res.data.link.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');
    document.querySelector('.status').classList.add('bg-success');
    document.querySelector('.status').innerHTML = 'Image : ';
    document.querySelector('.loading-image').src = res.data.link;

    $('#IMG_URL').val(res.data.link);

  }
};
```

Comment: friend does not work here the changes made: https://jsfiddle.net/qov4wjzx/

Comment: i saw your code you sent me before   you used jquery in your website

Comment: test my code with the real website please  , and tell me if it's ok.

Comment: also you already have a function to send to your php server so you don't need function SendImgInfo delete it

Answer (score 0):

,not clear what you want ,  if you want to know the url of img uploaded you have to send it to your server there is no request going to a php page except the imgur

to send url from imgur response in this case in variable  `cover_page`

i made a function to send the variable cover_page to server `00.php` **change this to your page path**

`SendImgInfo(url)` will send uploaded img url after getting response from Imgur  inside `feedback` function

you can get the url  using   `$_POST['cover_page']`

workig code https://jsfiddle.net/rkv88/8w1z0a39/

[image]

.

.

also there's a problem with the RegEx url
here`var get_link = res.data.link.replace(/^http:\/\//i, 'https://');`

this the current result of RegEx  what you want it to be?

[image]

Comment: are you saying that php page don't receive `cover_page` variable ?

Comment: please can you clarify your situation??

Comment: also there is other input the image file  browser  has the name set to cover_page

Comment: i want to help but  , still don't know exactly you need to after uploading the image , what the End goal of your script  what you trying to achive ?

Comment: Friend, with the automatic generation of the script I cannot validate when said field is empty, when I have not uploaded an image since the input field is only generated when the script has uploaded an image to the server, you can check it here by submitting the form : [here link](http://ajax.learncodesource.org/ajax.php) instead if that input field is created manually now if it can be validated you can check it here by sending [here link](http://ajax.learncodesource.org/ajax1.php)

Comment: So the idea is to have this field `<input name = "cover_page" class = "image-url" value = "">` manually and that the response value when uploading the image is added to `<input name = " cover_page "class =" image-url "value =" ">` or another way that is possible would be that once the entire form is generated when loading the script and that said value when uploading an image is located in the same field `<input name = "cover_page" class = "image-url" value = "">`